# Android Emulator Camera not working

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0

i need to run a android emulator from the command line supporting google play store and camera.

Now for some reason i cannot see/access the camera setted to "webcam0" for the following Emulators

Setups where Camera App is **not working**

> ./emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_P -camera-back webcam0 -gpu swiftshader
>   -no-boot-anim -nojni -netfast -qemu -enable-kvm > emulator.log 2>&1 &
>
> ./emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_26 -camera-back webcam0 -gpu
>   swiftshader_indirect -no-boot-anim -nojni -netfast -qemu -enable-kvm >
>   emulator1.log 2>&1

Setup where Camera App **is working**

> ./emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_25 -camera-back webcam0 -gpu
>   swiftshader_indirect -no-boot-anim -nojni -netfast -qemu -enable-kvm >

So i don´t understand why both latest API_P and API_26 level the camera is not showing up and with API_25 here camera  works.

I would also be happy with API_25 with **Google Play Store App & Camera** working but somehow it seems i am forced to use API_P or API_26 image if i want to have Google Play Store built in.

This is really annoying and confusing. I just need any emulator with Google Play Store and Camera running.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?